# ¿como puedo saltarme las lineas en blanco cuando estoy leyendo un fichero en C++?

Tags: c++, string, stream

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de sobrecarga de operadores en c++ y debo leer unas fechas de un fichero, y mi problema viene cuando aparece una línea en blanco y al leerla el programa me devuelve una fecha que no quiero que devuelva(-85..../-85/..../-85....), ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo evitar que mi programa lea estas líneas en blanco?

Este es mi fragmento de código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& input, Fecha& d)
{   

    string fecha;

    input >> fecha;

    istringstream isstream(fecha);

    char sep;

    int dia, mes, ano;

    isstream >> dia >> sep >> mes >> sep >> ano;

        d.setDia(dia);
        d.setMes(mes);
        d.setAno(ano);

    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes enfocar el problema de varias maneras. Una de ellas pasa por consultar el siguiente caracter que se va a leer del fichero y, si es un salto de línea, lo ignoras:

```
while( true )
{
  int next = isstream.peek()
  if( next == EOF )
  {
    break; // Final de fichero
  }
  else if( std::isdigit(next) )
  { 
    isstream >> dia >> sep >> mes >> sep >> ano;
    break;
  }
  else
    istream.get(); // Descartamos el caracter y seguimos leyendo
}
```

Otra posible solución es usar `getline` para leer el archivo línea a línea. Después solo hay que procesar esa línea de forma individual:

```
while( true )
{
  std::string linea;
  std::getline(isstream, linea);

  if( isstream.eof() )
  {
    // Hemos llegado al final del archivo
    break;
  }
  else if( !linea.empty() )
  {
    std::stringstream sstream(linea); // Cargamos la línea en otro stream para procesarla
    sstream >> dia >> sep >> mes >> sep >> anio;
    break;
  }
}
```